# Loading jniopencv_core7109340164936655704.dll: for javacv

Tags: java, opencv, javacv

my pc is 32 bit and i download the opencv 2.4.2 ver for win32 and i ins. , i incude path to environmental varialble too. but still i got following exception

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 
C:\Users\Francis\AppData\Local\Temp\jniopencv_core7109340164936655704.dll: 
Can't find dependent libraries

how can i resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Following is the complete configure steps. let it check.

> 1. Install Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable Packages x86 [download link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5555)
> 2. Extract OpenCV-2.4.2-win-superpack.exe inside the root directory C:\
> 3. Configure path: Add the following environment variables in system path (Make Sure that the folder path is correct)
>      32-bit version of the JDK:
>      `C:\opencv\build\common\tbb\ia32\vc10\;C:\opencv\build\x86\vc10\bin\;`
> 4. add the .jar files (match with the version of your system) to build path of project.